# Is this a correct usage of error handling in a promise?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I am having a hard time understanding the best way to handle errors.
Is the code below a good practice?

Is there a better,shorter, easier to read way to handle flow and errors?

How can you code to handle all errors so they don't get swallowed? Thank you.

```
  privateProperties.setSearchedData = function (data, searchFor) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      switch (searchFor) {
        case "photos":
          try {
            var photoItems = [];

            if (data.items && data.items.constructor === Array) {
              data.items.forEach(function (value) {
                if (value.link) {
                  photoItems.push(value.link);
                } else {
                  console.error('Link is undefined');
                  reject(new Error('Link is undefined'));
                }
              });
              privateProperties._uiInstances['main'].uiReference.set("photos.photoItems",photoItems)
                .then(resolve(photoItems))
                .catch(function (error) {
                  reject(error);
                })
            } else {
              reject(new Error('Data.items is undefined or not array'));
            }
          } catch (e) {
            throw e;
          }
        break;

        case "videos":
        break
      }
    });

  };
```

Comment: Which call here is asynchronous? Is it `uiReference.set`? What are you returning a promise for?

Comment: yes uiReference.set is asynchronous

Comment: No. Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! In fact you don't seem to need promises at all in here.

Comment: Why do you pass a function to `catch`, but not use a function in `then`?

Comment: after reading all the replies and comments i have refactored to not use promise at all since it was not needed. Thank you all for you time dedication it has helped understand promises better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you can just write:

```
privateProperties.setSearchedData = function(data, searchFor) {
  switch (searchFor) {

    case "photos":
      if (!Array.isArray(data.items)) 
        return Promise.reject("data.items is undefined or not an array");

      const photoItems = data.items.map(item => item.link);

      if (photoItems.some(item => !item)) {
        console.error('Link is undefined');
        return Promise.reject("Link is undefined");
     }

      return privateProperties._uiInstances['main'].uiReference
        .set("photos.photoItems", photoItems);

    case "videos":
      return Promise.reject("videos not supported");
  }
}
```

You are essentially trying to return the `uiReference.set` promise, so just return it. There is no need to `catch` a rejection from it--the rejection will be passed through for the consumer to handle. There is no need to create your own promise, and then laboriously `resolve` or `reject` your own new promise based on its result. Just return the promise you want. The error checking can be done up front and an explicit rejected promise returned in that case.

Using `await`, this could look like the following. You can `throw` instead of returning `Promise.reject`. The `throw` will result in the function returning a rejected promise with that as a reason.

```
privateProperties.setSearchedData = async function(data, searchFor) {
  switch (searchFor) {
    case "photos":
      return privateProperties._uiInstances['main'].uiReference
        .set("photos.photoItems", data.items.map(item => item.link));

    case "videos":
      throw new Error("videos not supported");
  }
}
```

I've omitted the check for an array, since a non-array will cause the `.map` to fail, which will result in the entire function returning a promise rejected for some reason such as "Cannot read property `map` of null".

I've also assumed a redesign of `uiReference.set` to do the check for missing or null links, and reject if that happens, so we don't have to check that the links are all there either. When all is said and done, this function really needs to do nothing more than switch on `searchFor`, extract the links from the data items, and then call and return `uiReference.set`. Personally, I would prefer to have separate functions for searching photos and videos, in which case it becomes very clean:

```
privateProperties.setSearchedPhotosData = async function(data) {
  return privateProperties._uiInstances['main'].uiReference
    .set("photos.photoItems", data.items.map(item => item.link));
}
```

The only remaining purpose of the `async` is to turn a failure of `map` (when `data.items` is not an array) into a rejected promise. However, if this situation represents a coding error, rather than a semi-expectable situation that you want to handle, it might be better to just let it throw (by removing `async`).

Comment: s/can/should/ :-)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. ;) Use reject without `new Error` and when you catch an error don't use `throw` but `reject( e )`

Then later on you can say

```
privateProperties.setSearchedData( ... )
  .then( callback )
  .catch( errorCallback );
```

---

*Sidenote:* Split your code into more functions for better readability. I guess all inside `case "photos":` (except break) can be its own function.

Answer (score 0):

1. You catch all errors but then just throw them. It's completely equal to just not catch them in the first place. Use `reject` instead of `throw`.
2. Regarding an easier and more readable way to use Promises, You can use [async await](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9) which makes your code a lot more readable and concise, and use Promises under the hood. Then your function will look like that:

   privateProperties.setSearchedData = async function (data, searchFor) {

   ```
   switch (searchFor) {
       case "photos":
           var photoItems = [];

           if (data.items && data.items.constructor === Array) {
               data.items.forEach(function (value) {
                   if (value.link) {
                       photoItems.push(value.link);
                   } else {
                       console.error('Link is undefined');
                       throw new Error('Link is undefined');
                   }
               });
               privateProperties._uiInstances['main'].uiReference.set("photos.photoItems",photoItems);
               return photoItems;
           } else {
               throw new Error('Data.items is undefined or not array');
           }
           break;

       case "videos":
           break
   }
   ```

   };

Comment: The snippet you posted doesn't appear to use async/await?